# Aframe Laser-controls dosn't work with WMR headset in chrome canary

Tags: google-chrome, aframe, webvr

Aframe is working fine with WMR with recent Chrome canary but the Laser controls doesn't. It show a vive controller instead of the WMR controller and it doesn't work.

i'm getting this in console:

OBJLoader: 112.781005859375ms
browser.js:111 core:a-entity:warn Tried to remove `Object3D` of type:  mesh which was not defined.
MTLLoader.js:86 THREE.MTLLoader: .setTexturePath() has been renamed to .setResourcePath().
setTexturePath @ MTLLoader.js:86
three.js:46130 THREE.Loader: .extractUrlBase() has been deprecated. Use THREE.LoaderUtils.extractUrlBase() instead.

Comment: Chrome Canary is undergoing through a lot of breaking changes. I recommend using regular Chrome. Use WebVR, Current WebXR spec doesn’t expose controller vendor to show appopriate model.

Comment: but regular chrome doesn't  offer wmr support in flags :-(

Comment: Try enabling webvr instead webxr in Canary. Most likely will have to wait until the dust settles on the WebXR spec, since there no way to identify controllers at the moment.